# Caching class attributes in Python

Tags: python, memoization

I'm writing a class in python and I have an attribute that will take a relatively long time to compute, so **I only want to do it once**.  Also, it will not be needed by every instance of the class, so **I don't want to do it by default** in `__init__`.

I'm new to Python, but not to programming.  I can come up with a way to do this pretty easily, but I've found over and over again that the 'Pythonic' way of doing something is often much simpler than what I come up with using my experience in other languages.

Is there a 'right' way to do this in Python?

Comment: IMO none of these answers is correct. OP wanted a cached _class_ property, eg `Foo.something_expensive`. All these answers are about cached _instance_ properties, which means `something_expensive` will be recalculated for every new instance, which is less than optimal in most cases

Comment: As of Python 3.9, all of the below can now be wrapped as a `@classmethod`, which should give you a cached class property.

Comment: @JakeStevens-Haas I do not believe that is correct.  I tried making a cached class property in Python 3.10.2 by using the `@classmethod` and `@functools.cached_property` together -- in both orders -- and neither worked.  By contrast, the `@cachedclassproperty` decorator from the Dickens library did work for me.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

**3.8 ≤ Python**
[`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) and [`@functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) have been combined into [`@cached_property`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html?highlight=#functools.cached_property).

```
import functools
class MyClass:
    @functools.cached_property
    def foo(self):
        print("long calculation here")
        return 21 * 2
```

**3.2 ≤ Python < 3.8**

You should use both [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) and [`@functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) decorators:

```
import functools
class MyClass:
    @property
    @functools.lru_cache()
    def foo(self):
        print("long calculation here")
        return 21 * 2
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16099881/343834) has more detailed examples and also mentions a backport for previous Python versions.

**Python < 3.2**

The Python wiki has a [cached property decorator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Cached_Properties) (MIT licensed) that can be used like this:

```
import random
# the class containing the property must be a new-style class
class MyClass(object):
   # create property whose value is cached for ten minutes
   @cached_property(ttl=600)
   def randint(self):
       # will only be evaluated every 10 min. at maximum.
       return random.randint(0, 100)
```

Or any implementation mentioned in the others answers that fits your needs.

Or the above mentioned backport.

Comment: lru_cache has also been backported to python 2: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/functools32/3.2.3

Comment: -1 `lru_cache` has a default size of 128, cause the property function to be potentially called twice. If you were to use `lru_cache(None)` all instances will be kept alive permanently.

Comment: @orlp lru_cache has a default size of 128, for 128 different argument configurations.  This will only be an issue if you are generating more objects than your cache size, as the only changing argument here is self.  If you are generating so many objects, you really shouldn't be using an unbounded cache, as it will force you to keep all objects that have ever called the property in memory indefinitely, which could be a horrendous memory leak.  Regardless, you probably would be better off with a caching method that stores the cache in the object itself, so the cache is cleaned up with it.

Comment: The `@property @functools.lru_cache()` method is giving me a `TypeError: unhashable type` error, presumably because `self` is not hashable.

Comment: Watch out! It appears to me `functools.lru_cache` causes instances of the class to avoid GC as long as they are in the cache. Better solution is `functools.cached_property` in Python 3.8.

Comment: Bit misleading to say "`@property` and `@functools.lru_cache` have been combined into `@cached_property`." [This answer shows how the 2 can be combined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16099881) but doesn't behave like `@cachedproperty` if you try setting a new value without writing a setter. In your 2 example snippets try `x=MyClass()`, `print(x.foo)`, `x.foo=6*9` to see the difference. From the docs: "The mechanics of `cached_property()` are somewhat different from `property()`. A regular property blocks attribute writes unless a setter is defined. In contrast, a cached_property allows writes."

Comment: It's important to note that `cached_property` has the [potential for a race condition in a multithreaded environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property) so if you need to avoid the potential race condition, you'll have to implement locking as well.

Answer (score 60):

I used to do this how gnibbler suggested, but I eventually got tired of the little housekeeping steps.

So I built my own descriptor:

```
class cached_property(object):
    """
    Descriptor (non-data) for building an attribute on-demand on first use.
    """
    def __init__(self, factory):
        """
        <factory> is called such: factory(instance) to build the attribute.
        """
        self._attr_name = factory.__name__
        self._factory = factory

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        # Build the attribute.
        attr = self._factory(instance)

        # Cache the value; hide ourselves.
        setattr(instance, self._attr_name, attr)

        return attr
```

Here's how you'd use it:

```
class Spam(object):

    @cached_property
    def eggs(self):
        print 'long calculation here'
        return 6*2

s = Spam()
s.eggs      # Calculates the value.
s.eggs      # Uses cached value.
```

Comment: Wonderful! Here's how it works: Instance variables [take precedence over non-data descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol). At the first access of the attribute, there is no instance attribute but only the descriptor class attribute and hence the descriptor is executed. However, during its execution the descriptor creates an instance attribute with the cached value. This means that when the attribute is accessed a second time the previously created instance attribute is returned instead of the descriptor being executed.

Comment: There is a [`cached_property` package on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cached-property). It includes thread-safe and time-expire versions. (Also, thanks, @Florian, for the explanation.)

Comment: Yay for esoteric corner cases: you can't use a `cached_property` descriptor when using `__slots__`. Slots are implemented using data descriptors, and using a `cached_property` descriptor simply overrides the generated slot descriptor, so the `setattr()` call won't work as there is no `__dict__` to set the attribute in and the only descriptor available for this attribute name is the `cached_property`.. Just putting this here to help others avoid this pitfall.

Comment: This solution didn't work with nested DRF Serializer, but the `cached_property package on PyPI` suggested by @leewz did the job.

Answer (score 43):

The usual way would be to make the attribute a [property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) and store the value the first time it is calculated

```
import time

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._bar = None

    @property
    def bar(self):
        if self._bar is None:
            print "starting long calculation"
            time.sleep(5)
            self._bar = 2*2
            print "finished long caclulation"
        return self._bar

foo=Foo()
print "Accessing foo.bar"
print foo.bar
print "Accessing foo.bar"
print foo.bar
```

Comment: In Python3.2+, is there any motivation to use this approach over `@property + @functools.lru_cache()`? The quasi-private attribute way seems to be reminiscent of Java/setters/getters; in my humble opinion just decorating with lru_cache is more pythonic

Comment: (As in @Maxime's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19979379/7954504))

Comment: @Brad `@functools.lru_cache()` would cache the result keyed with the `self` arg, and this would also prevent that instance from being GC'd as long as it was in the cache.

Comment: With this method, my IDE can easily auto-complete.

Answer (score 23):

Python 3.8 includes the [`functools.cached_property`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property) decorator.

> Transform a method of a class into a property whose value is computed
>   once and then cached as a normal attribute for the life of the
>   instance. Similar to `property()`, with the addition of caching. Useful
>   for expensive computed properties of instances that are otherwise
>   effectively immutable.

This example is straight from the docs:

```py
from functools import cached_property

class DataSet:
    def __init__(self, sequence_of_numbers):
        self._data = sequence_of_numbers

    @cached_property
    def stdev(self):
        return statistics.stdev(self._data)

    @cached_property
    def variance(self):
        return statistics.variance(self._data)
```

The limitation being that the object with the property to be cached must have a `__dict__` attribute that is a mutable mapping, ruling out classes with `__slots__` unless `__dict__` is defined in `__slots__`.

Answer (score 18):

As mentioned, `functools.cached_property` will work for cached *instance* attributes. For cached *class* attributes:

**3.9 <= python < 3.13**

```
from functools import cache

class MyClass:
    @classmethod
    @property
    @cache  # or lru_cache() for python < 3.9
    def foo(cls):
        print('expensive calculation')
        return 42
```

```
>>> MyClass.foo
expensive calculation
42
>>> MyClass.foo
42
```

And if you want a reusable decorator:

```
def cached_class_attr(f):
    return classmethod(property(cache(f)))

class MyClass:
    @cached_class_attr
    def foo(cls):
        ...
```

**python >= 3.13**

In 3.13 chaining `classmethod` and `property` is disallowed so you will have to use metaclasses or a custom decorator, here's an example of a read-only cached attribute:

```
class MyMeta(type):
    @property
    @cache
    def foo(self):
        ...

class MyClass(metaclass=MyMeta):
    ...

MyClass.foo  # read-only access
```

Or alternatively a custom decorator:

```
class classproperty:
    def __init__(self, func) -> None:
        functools.update_wrapper(self, func)
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.__wrapped__(owner)

class MyClass:
    @classproperty
    @cache
    def foo(cls):
        ...
```

Comment: Only took 12 years and 10 other (highly voted) answers for someone to finally give the correct one. Thanks

Comment: Why python < 3.11? Anything changed on this in 3.11?

Comment: @Davy stacking descriptions (classmethod, property) no longer allowed  :(

Comment: i can't see anywhere that stacking decorators is no longer allowed in 3.11
Additionally the code above works for me in 3.11.1

Comment: in 3.11, chaining classmethod and property is deprecated, but may still work for a while, see note here: https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/functions.html#classmethod

Answer (score 5):

The [`dickens`](https://pypi.org/project/Dickens/) package (not mine) offers `cachedproperty`, `classproperty` and `cachedclassproperty` decorators.

To cache a **class property**:

```
from descriptors import cachedclassproperty

class MyClass:
    @cachedclassproperty
    def approx_pi(cls):
        return 22 / 7
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class MemoizeTest:

      _cache = {}
      def __init__(self, a):
          if a in MemoizeTest._cache:
              self.a = MemoizeTest._cache[a]
          else:
              self.a = a**5000
              MemoizeTest._cache.update({a:self.a})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try looking into memoization. The way it works is that if you pass in a function the same arguments, it will return the cached result. You can find more information on [implementing it in python here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize).

Also, depending on how your code is set up (you say that it is not needed by all instances) you could try to use some sort of flyweight pattern, or lazy-loading.

Answer (score 1):

Most if not all current answers are about caching *instance* attributes. To cache *class* attributes, you can simply use a dictionary. This ensures the attributes are calculated once per class, instead of once per instance.

```py
mapping = {}

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        if self.__class__.__name__ not in mapping:
            print('Expansive calculation')
            mapping[self.__class__.__name__] = self.__class__.__name__
        self.cached = mapping[self.__class__.__name__]
```

To illustrate,

```py
foo = A()
bar = A()
print(foo.cached, bar.cached)
```

gives

```
Expansive calculation
A A
```

Answer (score -3):

The most simple way of doing this would probably be to just write a method (instead of using an attribute) that wraps around the attribute (getter method). On the first call, this methods calculates, saves and returns the value; later it just returns the saved value.

Answer (score -4):

With Python 2, but not Python 3, here's what I do. This is about as efficient as you can get:

```
class X:
    @property
    def foo(self):
        r = 33
        self.foo = r
        return r
```

Explanation: Basically, I'm just overloading a property method with the computed value. So after the first time you access the property (for that instance), `foo` ceases to be a property and becomes an instance attribute. The advantage of this approach is that a cache hit is as cheap as possible because `self.__dict__` is being used as the cache, and there is no instance overhead if the property is not used.

This approach doesn't work with Python 3.