# how to skip a classes __init__ (when inheriting) if it has a long startup time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

I have a python project with the following structure:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
       # Long startup

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)

class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
```

The problem is that `A` takes a long time to initialize, and I don't want to have to run it twice. Is it possible to "skip" the `__init__` of `A` on any occurrence *after* the first one?

I know that I can inherit `B` in `C` (rather than `A`), but that doesn't seem natural, seeing as `B` and `C` are completely different parts of my program.

Comment: How do instances of `B` and `C` interact? Why can't you keep track of how many times one of them has been initialized? Is it not possible to do `A.__init__` only within `B` and not `C`? It's a little hard to give you an answer without knowing

Comment: Depends on that A is doing. It might make sense for it to either have lazy initialization or share something that only one created for A between all its instances as a class variable.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226721/python-class-member-lazy-initialization) what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes, but it might not be appropriate or applicable to your situation.

Comment: I see. it seems to work. Thank you.