# Expensive operation in parent class performed once for all child classes

Tags: python, inheritance, super

I have two classes that inherit from the same base class. In the base class I have a very expensive method that must be ran only once and whose generated attributes must be available to the child class. How do I achieve that?

In the example below, the instantiation of the `B` and `C` child classes will both run `expensive_op` in `A`. I'd like `expensive_op` to be called only when I call `b=B()`. `A` is never called directly.

Moreover, I want to be able to modify the attributes of the parent class from the child class as done, for example, in the `modify` method in `B`.

Anyone able to help?

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    self.expensive_op()
  def expensive_op(self):
    self.something = #something ugly and expensive

class B(A):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
  def modify(self,mod):
    self.something = self.something+mod

class C(A):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    
b = B()
c = C()
```

EDIT: in response to @0x5453's comment, do you mean the modification of A below?

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    self.something = None
  def expensive_op(self):
    if self.something is not None:
      self.something = #something ugly and expensive
```

But if I call `b=B()` and then `c=C()`, the latter won't know about `self.something`. The output is

```
b=B()
c=C()
b.expensive_op(3)
print(b.something)
>>> 3
print(c.something is None)
>>> True
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You can turn `self.something` into a class attribute of `A`, so that its value will be shared among all instances of `A` (which includes children of `A`).  Default it to `None` and then only run `expensive_op` if `something is None`.

Comment: Are you averse to directly calling the parent class in the children, like `A.something = A.something+mod` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Caching class attributes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037481/caching-class-attributes-in-python) and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226721/python-class-member-lazy-initialization