# Function call from another function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, class

I've the following functions

```
def query_url_input() -> Dict:
    # code
    # fetch input from another url
    return output_dict

def process_query(queryid: str) -> Dict:
   d = query_url_input()    # how to call this only once
   # code uses requests/urllib with key value input of d + queryid to return results
   value = results
   return {queryid: value}

if __name__ == '__main__':
   for item in ['1.2', 'w.2', 'c.q']
       output = process_query(queryid=item)
```

In the above sample code, the function `process_query` is called multiple times and `query_url_input`
is also called from `process_query` multiple times. But for all the calls `query_url_input` returns the same output. So I want to call `query_url_input` only once(first call) and store `d` for later calls. I would like to ask for suggestions on how to do this using a `Class`.(I've used classes in MATLAB for performing similar tasks, but I am not sure how this has to be done in Python).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) decorator (python >= 3.2) for this purpose.You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16099881/4439753).

```
import functools
 
@functools.lru_cache()
def query_url_input():
    print("query_url_input")
    output_dict = dict()
    return output_dict

def process_query(queryid):
    print("process_query")
    d = query_url_input()
    value = "Some results"
    return {queryid: value}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for item in ['1.2', 'w.2', 'c.q']:
        output = process_query(queryid=item)
```

output:

```
process_query
query_url_input
process_query
process_query
```